# How can i add my custom npm package to TypeScript Definition manager?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

i have created couple of custom npm modules with `javascript`. Not so long ago i started to experiment with `typescript`. So there is my question. How can i add my packages to `TypeScript Definition manager` ? Or maybe i should rewrite them into `typescript` and then what ?

[TypeScript Definition manager](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/)

In my project i am using [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/), maybe i should not create any definition and maybe you know some ***GOOD*** way of using my modules with typescript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tsd` has now given way to `typings`. The procedure to adding your typings is given here: https://github.com/typings/registry

I'd avoid rewriting to TypeScript - while that would make managing them in the future much easier, it might just do for you to have your own `declare`s stacked up into a Typings file, which would be significantly easier